# Не работает запись в TXT файл c#

Tags: c#, txt

Код:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "By.txt");

        foreach (string skin in skins)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(skin);
        }
```

Файл по идее открывается, так как если перед запуском что-то в него написать то все стирается. Переменная skin не пустая, я проверял.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Добрый день. Можно весь код привести, пожалуйста? Какую ошибку выдает? Уверены, что файл находится по пути в директории?

Comment: using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "By.txt"), false,System.Text.Encoding.Default)) { ....}

Comment: Насчет нахождения в, директории, файл очищается при запуске программы

Comment: @Konst `new UTF8Encoding(false)`, не используйте Default, потому что на разных платформах и разных детнетах она разная. Файл, записанный в одном месте, может не получиться прочитать в другом.

Comment: Вы забыли закрыть `sw`. Нужно либо `sw.Close()` вызвать, либо `using` использовать. Второе лучше.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо!